# Identify Salesforce Merged Records (Kimble)

Tags: merge, salesforce

I'm in the process of creating a data warehouse from Sales Force Kimble data.  Data is retrieved using the Kimble API.

The way I understand the merge record process is that when 2, or more, records are identified as duplicate these can be merged into one, reusing the `Id` of the record marked as the `master` record, and the other records are effectively hard deleted.

Is there a way to identify such merged records?

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch something over raw Salesforce APIs, no idea if "Kimble" exposes these bits?

Let's say I executed this ("merge winner loser")

```
merge new Account(Id = '0017000000vXh3lAAC') new Account(Id = '0017000000vXh3mAAC');
```

Merge's result should be written to **winner's field history**.

[image]

You can query the history

```
SELECT CreatedDate, Field, OldValue, NewValue
FROM AccountHistory
WHERE AccountId = '0017000000vXh3lAAC' AND Field = 'accountMerged'
```

```
"CreatedDate": "2023-09-25T21:50:49.000+0000",
"Field": "accountMerged",
"OldValue": "Acc 2",
"NewValue": null
```

**Loser** went to the Bin and you need special syntax to pull these records (depending on which API you're using) but if you can fetch them - winner's id was written to it just before the delete:

```
SELECT Id, Name, MasterRecordId
FROM Account
WHERE Id = '0017000000vXh3mAAC'
```

This should be enough for you to start experimenting. Of course there are more options like Change Data Capture / custom platform events / flow or trigger firing on delete (if you go this route [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_merge_statements.htm) may be a good read)

I'd say the history route is bit more predictable than pulling them from Bin. You never know if Bin wasn't emptied (manually or by SF themselves due to data volumes). It's not 100% foolproof, a determined admin can delete the field history entries too - but it's something. The downside is that this history entry contains record's Name, not Id...

Comment: This is a start for sure.  it would be nice if SF used soft deletes instead. it would make this a lot easier.